# Таблица из Excel в другую таблицу

Tags: c#, excel

Допустим есть 3 столбца. В 1 столбце номер(a1), во втором название(b1), в третьем описание(c1).
Я хочу сделать еще 1 таблицу, так что бы данные перекинулись в нее, но с 1 условием.
Если в 3 столбце, в одной ячейке символов больше чем допустим 500, то продолжить копировать данные со строк в следующую ячейку. (К примеру  есть строка a2,b2,c2. В ячейке c2 получилось 600 символов, тогда оставшиеся символы перенести на одну ячейку нижу, c3 и скопировать туда текст из ячеек a2,b2)
Возможно ли как то проследить это? Сделать, какой-то счетчик, что бы он считал символы в ячейке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что тут делает тег шарпа? это надо сделать программно из него? *какой-то счетчик, что бы он считал символы в ячейке.* Функция листа ДЛСТР().

Comment: Да нужно программно. А что в самом excel это тоже можно сделать?

Comment: Ну есть же у строкового типа способы определения размера (свойство Length) и выделения подстроки (метод Substring)... Чего нехватает?

Comment: Не понимаю, как это можно сделать. Можете помочь? Я сделал скриншот, как должно получиться.

Comment: Сделать можно всё. Если дело за экселем - попробуйте почитать про библиотеку NPOI, там всё здорово описано с примерами.

Comment: А на русском нет ничего? А то с английским проблемы. Если не трудно, то приму пример именно по моему вопросу.